# Macro doesn't protect back my ws properly

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I am having a small issue with macro that is suppose to unprotect my worksheet, refresh Pivot Table and protect ws again (with condition). It works OK only partially as it does unprotect the ws, it refreshes the Pivot Table, but after that something strange is happening:
- it doesn't really restore back rows and columns formatting
- it doesn't protect the ws back properly (my ws looks like it is protected when you click on Tools,Protection - but, you can unprotect it without entering password again ??!!

```
    Sub RefreshPivotTables()
    ' will remove password and refresh PT
    Dim xpt As PivotTable
        With ActiveSheet
            .Unprotect Password:="milessss"
            For Each xpt In Worksheets("WT-1").PivotTables
                xpt.RefreshTable
            Next xpt
            .Protect Password:="milessss", AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, EnableOutlining:=True
        End With
    End Sub
```

[image: See image attached]

Can anybody help please ?
Cheers - Mile`S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo mistake:

```
  .Protect AllowFormattingRows:=True
  .Protect AllowFormattingColumns:=True
```

`Rows` instead of `Raws` and `Columns` instead of `Column`

Source : [Protection.AllowFormattingRows Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/protection-allowformattingrows-property-excel)

Typo was corrected, but to achieve your goal, you need to use this code:

```
Private Sub RefreshPivotTables()
' will remove password and refresh PT

Dim xpt As pivotTable
With ActiveSheet
  .Unprotect Password:="milessss"
  For Each xpt In .PivotTables
      xpt.RefreshTable
  Next xpt
  .Protect Password:="milessss", AllowFormattingCells:=True,AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End With
End Sub
```

In fact, you are using the Protect function multiple times with different options. So each time you use it, you erase the older options you used. Thus at the end of your macro, the only available property is `AllowUsingPivotTables` but no password it set. So you need to set all your arguments in a single expression.

Comment: Thank you Jean ... I am really tired, but still it is a shame I haven't seen those typos :(  Now, I discovered the real problem with this macro - I have changed my question to describe the problem properly - macro doesn't protect back my ws the way it should. What would be the reason for this? It is excel 2003 ...

Comment: @Miles What do you mean, it doesn't protect as it should ? Your macro allows editing of the rows and columns since you set these to True ? I don't understand your issue, could you explain it ?

Comment: My ws is protected without password ... and Allow cells, rows & columns formatting are still not selected (allow using Pivot Table report is OK)

Comment: So, when I click on Tools, Protection - unprotect sheet, I am not asked for password ...

Comment: Just edited my comments - I missed to say that formatting cells is not selected either (after macro executed)

Comment: @Miles works now, sorry I didn't catch it earlier, my VBA is a bit rusty

Comment: Jean, sorry to bother you again, the conditions are fine now, you fixed it ... the protection is still a problem .... there is no protection at all after macro is executed !!

Comment: @Miles the code works perfectly, it does protect with your password. Only thing I can think about not protecting is that you're not on the sheet you want to protect when you run it, or something like that. But code wise, it does its job. So I need more details

Comment: Hi Jean, I am not sure how it happens that we have different results ... This whole line is highlighted in yellow:                                       .Protect Password:="milessss", AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, EnableOutlining:=True

Comment: I have updated my macro - please have a look at my original question

Comment: Hi Jean, I did further testing and confirmed that you were right and your solution for the problem is correct. Pls accept my apology for not seeing it properly and on time. I have added a small code to the existing macro and that appears to be a problem - EnableOutlining:=True        I am trying to be able to delete a button and a comment after macro is executed and the error keeps pointing on this little code. Have you got any advise how to include this together with 'AllowFormattinRows, Columns and Cells' ?

Comment: Jean, after more testing, I found how to enable object editing in a protected worksheet, simply by adding - DrawingObjects:=False

Comment: With the above, I have everything what I needed. Thank you very much for solving the major issue for me.  Cheers !!!